# Errors using Requests module in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have recently been trying to make a web scraper using the requests module in python.

At first it was working, then i received the Response 403 error and then when I went back and tested the output for websites I had already scraped I got the Response 200 error. I was wondering if anyone knew why this is the case.

In the code below, I get the response 200 for collect_omers and collect_real and then response 403 for collect_bdc.
Thanks

```
import requests,bs4

def collect_omers():
    acquired_list = []
    logo_list = []
    omers_html = requests.get('https://www.omersventures.com/portfolio-summary')
    print(omers_html)
    omers_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(omers_html.text,"html.parser")
    omers_tags = omers_soup.select('.field-content a')
    for logo in omers_tags:
        if "portfolio" in str(logo) and logo.get_text() != "":
            if "acquired" in logo.get_text().lower():
                acquired_list.append(logo.get_text())
            else:
                logo_list.append(logo.get_text())

def collect_real():
    acquired_list = []
    logo_list = []
    real_html = requests.get('https://realventures.com/backing/')
    print(real_html)
    real_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(real_html.text,"html.parser")
    real_tags = real_soup.select('.company-list__grid-item')
    count = 1
    for logo in real_tags:
        listed = logo.get_text().strip().split("\n")
        if len(listed)>3:
            acquired_list.append(listed[0].strip() + " " + "(" + listed[3] + ")")
        else:
            logo_list.append(listed[0].strip())

def collect_bdc():
    acquired_list = []
    logo_list = []
    bdc_html = requests.get('https://www.inovia.vc/portfolio/')
    print(bdc_html)
    bdc_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(bdc_html.text,"html.parser")

    bdc_tags = bdc_soup.select('.row')
    count = 1
    for logo in bdc_tags:
        print(logo.get_text())


collect_real()
```

Comment: "Response 200" isn't an error. HTTP 200 is literally the "OK" code. 

HTTP 403, on the other hand, is "Forbidden".

Answer (score 0):

Response 200 is good -- it means your request went through and a response was returned.

The 403 response from the 3rd site does mean that something went wrong. Taking a look at it, it seems like the 3rd site automatically rejects GET requests that don't provide a user-agent header. You can find your own user-agent header by pressing F12 in Chrome, clicking to the "Network" tab, navigating to the site, and clicking on the corresponding request in the list. The user-agent header will be under the "Request Headers" section. You must provide this header via the `requests.get()` `headers` keyword argument.

The code will look something like this:

```
    bdc_html = requests.get('https://www.inovia.vc/portfolio/', headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36'})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate it